# Jersey REST client not creating database

Tags: java, mysql, rest

I've been trying to link my REST web service to a database programmatically but can't succeed in doing so. I'm new to this, so I followed some tutorials and watched some videos yet nothing I do works.

Below is my Database handler file:

```
import com.feedme.model.Food;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDBHandler {
// List of variables
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "restaurants";

public static final String TABLE_FOOD = "food";
public static final String FOOD_COLUMN_ID = "_fid";
public static final String FOOD_COLUMN_NAME = "fname";
public static final String FOOD_COLUMN_PRICE = "fprice";
public static final String FOOD_COLUMN_ICON = "ficon";
public static final String MENU_COLUMN_ID = "_mid";
public static final String RESTO_COLUMN_ID = "_rid";
public static final String FOOD_COLUMN_SUPPLEMENTS = "fsupplements";

public static String strSeparator = "__,__";

// JDBC driver name and database URL  
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/";

// Database credentials
static final String USER = "user";
static final String PASS = "password";

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("In MyDBHandler.java");
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement db = null;

    try {

        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // Open a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        db = conn.createStatement();

        // Create the resto database
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE " + DATABASE_NAME;
        db.executeUpdate(sql);

        // Create the food table
        String food = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOOD + "(" +
            FOOD_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " + ", " +
            FOOD_COLUMN_NAME + " VARCHAR(20) " + ", " +
            FOOD_COLUMN_PRICE + " VARCHAR(20) " + ", " +
            FOOD_COLUMN_ICON + " VARCHAR(20) " + ", " +
            RESTO_COLUMN_ID + " VARCHAR(20) " + ", " +
            MENU_COLUMN_ID + " VARCHAR(20) " + ", " +
            FOOD_COLUMN_SUPPLEMENTS + " VARCHAR(20) " +
            ")";
        db.executeUpdate(food);

    }catch(SQLException se){
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
        try{
            if(db != null)
                db.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){

        }
        try{
           if(conn != null)
              conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
           se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
    }//end try
}    

// Add a new food to the Food table
public Food addFood(Food food) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement db = null;

    try {
        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // Open a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        db = conn.createStatement();

        String suppString = convertArrayToString(food.getSupplements());

        String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_FOOD + " VALUES(" + food.getFname() +
                ", " + food.getFprice() + ", " + food.getFicon() + ", " + food.getrId() +
                ", " + food.getmId() + ", " + suppString + ");";
        db.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch(SQLException se){
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
        try{
            if(db != null)
                db.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){

        }
        try{
           if(conn != null)
              conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
           se.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }

    return food;
}
```

I expect to have the database and table created, and then populate the table through a post request. But nothing happens.

Below is the resource file supposed to make the call to the database (It doesn't seem to do so though):

```
@Path("/foods/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FoodResource {

MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler();

@GET
public List<Food> getFoods() {
    List<Food> foodList = dbHandler.getAllFoods();

    return foodList;
}

@POST
public Food addFood(Food food) {
    return dbHandler.addFood(food);                
}

@PUT
@Path("/{foodId}")
public Food updateFood(@PathParam("messageId") long id, Food food) {
    return dbHandler.updateFood(id, food);
}

@DELETE
@Path("/{messageId}")
public void deleteMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long id) {
    dbHandler.deleteFood(id);
}

@GET
@Path("/{foodId}")
public Food getFood(@PathParam("foodId") long id) {        
    return dbHandler.getFood(id);        
}

}
```

I get nothing on the exceptions log so it leaves me really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new is tough but here are a few things to get you going. There are several problems with the code provided. I would double check your url for connecting to mysql. It doesn't look right to me. You are also attempting to connect to the database `restaurants` before you've created it.

You are catching several exceptions and printing them out. I've surprised you aren't see any of these with the code you have when running it (I did when running your code). It is always useful to provided exception information in questions.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Phil. I just edited the post. I actually get nothing on my exception log. What could be wrong?

Comment: When I run your code's main method, it doesn't get past `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);` without throwing an exception. Have you tried putting in print statements or stepping through the code with a debugger? (I still think your URL is wrong.)